# Change frame of JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

How can I change the frame to `JSQMessagesViewController` to display in half screen

[image]?

```
 self.collectionView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250)
```

above is not changing frame.

Answer (score 0):

Add collectionview bottom contraints with respect to your custom view.

Bottom of collectionview to top of custom view